# Gephi: filter nodes and its neighbors

Tags: gephi

I'm using Gephi to filter down a node using its ID. But, I need to change this so that all neighbors (connected nodes) also get filtered too. I tried using the "Neighbor Network" filter in conjunction to the Label filter but that doesn't seem to work. I still see just one node selected.

[image: Here's my filter]

Comment: See "Ego network" in Gephi's topology filter folder.

Comment: Go the "Data Laboratory", in order to see the ID of the node, for which you want the ego network.... 'Ego network' filter uses the *node ids* not the *Labels*